# Count number of each char in a String

Tags: java, strings

I know there is a simpler way of doing this, but I just really can't think of it right now. Can you please help me out?

```
String sample = "hello world";
char arraysample[] = sample.toCharArray();
int length = sample.length();

//count the number of each letter in the string
int acount = 0;
int bcount = 0;
int ccount = 0;
int dcount = 0;
int ecount = 0;
int fcount = 0;
int gcount = 0;
int hcount = 0;
int icount = 0;
int jcount = 0;
int kcount = 0;
int lcount = 0;
int mcount = 0;
int ncount = 0;
int ocount = 0;
int pcount = 0;
int qcount = 0;
int rcount = 0;
int scount = 0;
int tcount = 0;
int ucount = 0;
int vcount = 0;
int wcount = 0;
int xcount = 0;
int ycount = 0;
int zcount = 0; 

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    char c = arraysample[i];
    switch (c) 
    {
        case 'a': 
            acount++;
            break;
        case 'b': 
            bcount++;
            break;
        case 'c': 
            ccount++;
            break;
        case 'd': 
            dcount++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            ecount++;
            break;
        case 'f':
            fcount++;
            break;
        case 'g':
            gcount++;
            break;
        case 'h':
            hcount++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            icount++;
            break;
        case 'j':
            jcount++;
            break;
        case 'k':
            kcount++;
            break;
        case 'l':
            lcount++;
            break;
        case 'm':
            mcount++;
            break;
        case 'n':
            ncount++;
            break;
        case 'o':
            ocount++;
            break;
        case 'p':
            pcount++;
            break;
        case 'q':
            qcount++;
            break;
        case 'r':
            rcount++;
            break;
        case 's':
            scount++;
            break;
        case 't':
            tcount++;
            break;
        case 'u':
            ucount++;
            break;
        case 'v':
            vcount++;
            break;
        case 'w':
            wcount++;
            break;
        case 'x':
            xcount++;
            break;
        case 'y':
            ycount++;
            break;
        case 'z':
            zcount++;
            break;
        }
}
System.out.println ("There are " +hcount+" h's in here ");
System.out.println ("There are " +ocount+" o's in here ");
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Oh woah! xD It's just.. woah! What patience you have to write all those variables.

Well, it's Java so you can use a HashMap.

Write something like this:

```
String str = "Hello World";
int len = str.length();
Map<Character, Integer> numChars = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(Math.min(len, 26));

for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    char charAt = str.charAt(i);

    if (!numChars.containsKey(charAt))
    {
        numChars.put(charAt, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        numChars.put(charAt, numChars.get(charAt) + 1);
    }
}

System.out.println(numChars);
```

1. We do a `for` loop over all the string's characters and save the current char in the `charAt` variable
2. We check if our HashMap already has a `charAt` key inside it

   - If it's true we will just get the current value and add one.. this means the string has already been found to have this char.
   - If it's false (i.e. we never found a char like this in the string), we add a key with value 1 because we found a new char
3. Stop! Our HashMap will contain all chars (keys) found and how many times it's repeated (values)!

Comment: As an added bonus, this also supports more than just lower case letters.

Comment: You might consider a TreeMap instead of a HashMap so that the data, when printed, is ordered by the collection itself (if you were going to print them all).  If you are going to stay with a HashMap, you might consider the initalcapacity argument on the constructor as you're not going to get more than 26 letters in this situation.  Best practices and all that.

Comment: @MichaelT TreeMap great! I would anyway set the initialSize to str.length() since it could be every char is never repeated.

Comment: Then it would be `min(str.len(),26)` because if it is longer than 26 characters there *will* be duplicated characters... though we're both kind of ignoring spaces.  Still, its only a hint to the system and it will grow if it needs to.  The default to start with is 16 (and then it grows to 32, and then to 64).  I'd still use one of the [navigablemap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementations for its sorted nature.  I kind of like the skip list.

Comment: Yup, min(str.length(), 26). It's just to avoid the "grow cost"  if not needed

Comment: +1 especially for the "_woah_"s and the "_Stop!_"

Answer (score 22):

A possibly faster, and at least more compact version than using a `HashMap` is to use a good old integer array. A `char` can actually be typecasted to an `int`, which gives it's ASCII code value.

```
String str = "Hello World";
int[] counts = new int[(int) Character.MAX_VALUE];
// If you are certain you will only have ASCII characters, I would use `new int[256]` instead

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char charAt = str.charAt(i);
    counts[(int) charAt]++;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts));
```

As the above output is a bit big, by looping through the integer array you can output just the characters which actually occur:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    if (counts[i] > 0)
        System.out.println("Number of " + (char) i + ": " + counts[i]);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast `Character.MAX_VALUE` to an int, nor do you need to cast `chartAt` to an int. Internally they are represented as numbers and will work just fine. You can even use `char i` instead of `int i` in your printing loop to avoid the cast to `char` there as well.

The nice thing about making it an array like this is that it can make for very readable code. You can get the count for any char by just saying `counts['a']` to get the count for 'a'.

Answer (score 9):

1. Actually, there is an even better structure than maps and arrays for this kind of counting: [`Multiset`s](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained). [Documentation of Google Guava mentions a very similar case](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained):

   > The traditional Java idiom for e.g. counting how many times a word occurs in a document is something like:
   >
   > ```
   > Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   > for (String word : words) {
   >   Integer count = counts.get(word);
   >   if (count == null) {
   >     counts.put(word, 1);
   >   } else {
   >     counts.put(word, count + 1);
   >   }
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > This is awkward, prone to mistakes, and doesn't support collecting a variety of useful statistics, like the total number of words. We can do better.

   With a multiset you can get rid of the `contains` (or `if (get(c) != null)`) calls, what you need to call is a simple `add` in every iteration. Calling `add` the first time adds a single occurrence of the given element.

   ```
   String input = "Hello world!";

   Multiset<Character> characterCount = HashMultiset.create();
   for (char c: input.toCharArray()) {
       characterCount.add(c);
   }
   for (Entry<Character> entry: characterCount.entrySet()) {
       System.out.println(entry.getElement() + ": " + entry.getCount());
   }
   ```

   (See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)
2. > ```
   > int length = sample.length();
   > ....
   > for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   >     char c = arraysample[i];
   > ```

   You could replace these three lines with a foreach loop:

   ```
   for (char c: arraysample) {
   ```
3. > ```
   > int length = sample.length();
   > ....
   > for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   >     char c = arraysample[i];
   > ```

   You don't need the `length` variable, you could use `sample.length()` in the loop directly:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < sample.length(); i++) {
   ```

   The JVM is smart, it will optimize that for you.
4. > ```
   > char arraysample[] = sample.toCharArray();
   > int length = sample.length();
   > for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   >     char c = arraysample[i];
   > ```

   It's a little bit confusing that the loop iterating over `arraysample` but using `sample.length()` as the upper bound. Although their value is the same it would be cleaner to use `arraysample.length` as the upper bound.

Answer (score 5):

Yes... there is a simpler way. You have two choices, but each about the same. Use an Array, or a Map. The more advanced way of doing this would certainly be with a Map.

Think about a map as a type of array where instead of using an integer to index the array you can use anything. In our case here we'll use  char as the index. Because chars are ints you could just use a simple array in this case, and just mentally think of 'a' as 0, but we're going to take the larger step today.

```
String sample = "Hello World!";

// Initialization
Map <Character, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for(int c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++){
    counter.put((Character)c, 0);
}

// Populate
for (int i = 0; i < sample.length(); i++){
    if(counter.containsKey(sample.charAt(i)))
        counter.put(sample.charAt(i), counter.get(sample.charAt(i)) + 1 );
}
```

Now anytime you want to know how many of whatever character there was just call this method

```
int getCount(Character character){
    if(counter.containsKey(character))
        return counter.get(character);
    else return 0;
}
```

Note: This only will work for counting punctuation.

Comment: Your code will throw `NullPointerException` for `counter.get(s.charAt(i)) + 1` when char is not `'a'..'z'` :( `null + 1` throws.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg was just about to fix that, and make a note that this only counter letters

Comment: `containsKey(i)`? That sounds like a clear mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The use of functional programming can even simplify this problem to a great extent.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String myString = "hello world";

    System.out.println(
        myString
            .chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
            .filter(str -> !str.equals(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ch -> ch, Collectors.counting()))

    );
}
```

First we get the stream of integers from the string

```
myString.chars()
```

Next we transform the integers into string

```
mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
```

Then we filter out the charcters we don't need to consider, for example above we have filtered the spaces.

```
filter(str -> !str.equals(" "))
```

Then finally we collect them grouping by the characters and counting them

```
collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ch -> ch, Collectors.counting()))
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert the characters to strings? Why don't you use `.codePoints()` instead of `.chars()`?

Comment: What does the variable `p` stand for?

Comment: Sorry for that p, changed it to ch denoting character