# Web Crawler in Java

Tags: java, web-scraping

I've written a working web crawler in Java that finds the frequencies of words on web pages. I have two issues with it.

- The organization of my code in **WebCrawler.java** is terrible. Is there a way I could refactor the class to make it more readable? Perhaps splitting it into multiple classes?
- I want to find a way to group similar words, so that I don't have entries for every possible word(for example, `page` and `pages`).

This is **WebCrawler.java**:

```
public class WebCrawler {
    private static final int MAX_URL_QUEUE = 3000;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private List<Thread> threads;

    private int currentURLNum = 0;
    private final int MAXURL;
    private Queue<String> urlQqueue;

    private URLGroup crawledURLs;
    private WordExtractor words;

  public WebCrawler(String start, int max, int threads) {
      this.MAXURL = max;
      urlQqueue = new LinkedList<String>();
      urlQqueue.offer(start);
      this.threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

      words = new WordExtractor();
      for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++){
          this.threads.add(new Thread(new CrawlTask(this, words)));
      }
      crawledURLs = new URLGroup();
  }
  public void run(){
      for(Thread t : threads){
          t.start();
      }
      boolean allThreadsDead = false;
      while(!allThreadsDead){
          allThreadsDead = true;
          for(int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++){
              if(threads.get(i).isAlive()){
                  Thread.yield();
                  i = 0;
                  allThreadsDead = false;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  static class CrawlTask implements Runnable{
    private final WebCrawler bot;
    private final WordExtractor words;
    public CrawlTask(WebCrawler bot, WordExtractor words){
        this.bot = bot;
        this.words = words;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        URLGroup group = new URLGroup();
            while(bot.currentURLNum < bot.MAXURL){
                String url = bot.urlQqueue.poll();
                if(url == null){
                    Thread.yield();
                    continue;
                }       
                Document doc = null;
                try{
                    doc = bot.getDocument(url.toString(), 3000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }
                words.extractFromDocument(doc);
                List<String> urls = new LinkExtractor().extractFromDocument(doc).getCollectedURLs();

                synchronized(bot.lock){
                    bot.currentURLNum++;
                    group.add(url);
                    for(String u : urls){
                        if(bot.urlQqueue.size() > MAX_URL_QUEUE){
                            break;
                        }
                        bot.urlQqueue.offer(u);
                    }
                    System.out.println(bot.currentURLNum);
                }
            }    
            for(String u : group.urls){
                bot.crawledURLs.add(u);
            }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " is done!");
    }

  }

  private Document getDocument(String url, int timeout) throws IOException {
        return Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(timeout).get();
  }
// The Main Entry-point
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
      String startingUrl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random";

      WebCrawler bot = new WebCrawler(startingUrl, 50, 10);
      bot.run();
      bot.crawledURLs.printCrawled(System.out);
      bot.words.printTopWords(System.out, 30);
  }
```

And this is my current method of storing the frequencies of words:

```
public class WordExtractor implements DocumentExtractor{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> wordFrequency = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public void foundWord(String word){
        if(wordFrequency.get(word) == null){
            wordFrequency.put(word, 1);
        }else{
            wordFrequency.put(word, wordFrequency.get(word) + 1);
        }
    }

    public void printTopWords(OutputStream output, int num) throws IOException{
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> topWords = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            topWords.add(null);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = wordFrequency.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, Integer>)it.next();
            for(int i = 0; i < topWords.size(); i++){
                int topVal = 0;
                if(topWords.get(i) != null)
                    topVal = topWords.get(i).getValue();

                if(pairs.getValue() > topVal){
                    topWords.set(i, pairs);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        output.write(topWords.toString().getBytes());
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized DocumentExtractor extractFromDocument(Document doc) {
        String[] words = doc.body().text().split("\\s+");
        for(String word : words){
            foundWord(word.toLowerCase());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the obvious code-review, you could consider using Lucene with a RAMDirectory for indexing the documents, and that will 'stem' the words for you (pages -> page), as well as count the frequency. You can also have stop-words (ignore words, like 'the', 'and', etc.). natural Language Processing (NLP) is the general computing 'genre' for this type of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If I'm right you could eliminate most of the threading-logic with an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and an [`awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) call. The linked javadoc has some usage examples too. (Don't forget to check the return value of `awaitTermination`.)

   (*Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 47: Know and use the libraries*)
2. `int max` is a little bit mysterious. What does it maximize? I'd put that into the name.
3. `urlQqueue` is used from multiple threads without proper synchronization (`urlQqueue.poll()`), it's not thread-safe. [`Queue` has other, thread-safe implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), I'd use one of them instead of `LinkedList`.

   You could use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to avoid loops with `Thread.yield()` (which is rarely approprite, according to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29)):

   > ```
   > while (bot.currentURLNum < bot.MAXURL) {
   >     String url = bot.urlQqueue.poll();
   >     if (url == null) {
   >         Thread.yield();
   >         continue;
   >     }
   > ```
4. `currentURLNum` is also not properly synchronized, it is read by the `while` statement without synchronization.

   > [...] synchronization has no effect unless both read and write operations are synchronized.

   From *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*.
5. The reference type could be simply `Map<String, Integer>` here:

   > ```
   > private HashMap<String, Integer> wordFrequency = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   > ```

   See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
6. Actually, you could use a `Multiset` for counting the words. ([Here is a similar example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44208/7076))
7. You need some more synchronization for `WordExtractor`, since the underlying `HashMap` is not thread safe. `printTopWords` might not see your latest data. `foundWord` is also `public`, so if anyone call he or she could get weird results too.
8. Gauava has a helper method ([`copyHighestCountFirst`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst%28com.google.common.collect.Multiset%29)) for multisets which might be very similar to the algorithm in the `printTopWords` method.

   (*Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 47: Know and use the libraries* The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)